# Numpy array map

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe transformed to a numpy array after scaling.
Example: (let's say there is 1000 samples)

```
       [[ -3.12819390e-01  -1.92776011e-01  -5.86198203e-01 ...,   
           3.47114065e-01
           3.74794001e-01   2.89473684e-01]
        [ -7.99896504e-01  -8.35721640e-01  -8.70581173e-01 ...,   
           2.31696140e-01   2.36763880e-01   1.57894737e-01]
        [ -3.12819390e-01  -6.20289856e-02  -1.27139646e+00 ...,
```

I have another numpy array 1D that has 1 or -1 (1000 samples also)

```
       [1 1 -1 ..., 1 -1 1]
```

How can I keep the samples(from first array) that has a 1(from the 2nd array) and remove the samples that has -1 ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `boolean indexing`

```
arr1[:, arr2==1]
```

Comment: Oh wait, I've got IndexError: index 298 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 298

Comment: @hdatas The second array's length must be equal or less than dimension of  indexed array along dimension 1;